# How to select image from displayed horizontal listview and used as swipe image android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-popupwindow

I have an imageview and below is horizontal listview. So when I select image in horizontal listview, selected image will display in imageview. Now
when I click imageview, it should display in full screen with swipe images. I used view pager but I don't know how to get position of horizontal listview images and use it.

here is piece of code:

```
      public class ProductDetail extends Activity{
      ProductImagesAdapter gallery_adapter;
      PopupWindow popupMenuImage;
      HorizontalListView listView;
      public static int CURRENT_IMAGE=0;
     List<String> imageUrl=new ArrayList<String>();
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_detail);
           listView=(HorizontalListView)findViewById(R.id.product_images);
        aQuery=new AQuery(this);
           ivProductMain=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.product_main_image);
           listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                                // setting listview item in imageview.
                aQuery.id(ivProductMain).image(imageUrl.get(position), true, true, 0, R.drawable.default_large, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ProductDetail.this.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.default_large), 0);
                CURRENT_IMAGE=position;
                gallery_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
              // in post execute :
             gallery_adapter=new ProductImagesAdapter(ProductDetail.this, imageUrl);
                        listView.setAdapter(gallery_adapter);
                        if(imageUrl.size()>0)
                        {
                            aQuery.id(ivProductMain).image(imageUrl.get(0), false, false, 0, R.drawable.default_large, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ProductDetail.this.getResources(),
                                    R.drawable.default_large), 0);
                        }
            }
        public void onclick(View clickedView)
    {
        switch (clickedView.getId()) {
        case R.id.product_main_image:

            View parentRow = (View) clickedView.getParent();
            listView=(HorizontalListView)parentRow.getParent();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             //to display single item image, it's working since i am passing current image.
            /*View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pinch_zoom, null);

            popupMenuImage = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            TouchImageView ivZoom=(TouchImageView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.pinch_zoom_view);
            popupMenuImage.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
            popupMenuImage.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupMenuImage.setFocusable(true);
            popupMenuImage.setContentView(popupView);
            popupMenuImage.showAtLocation(clickedView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); // Display the popup
            aQuery.id(ivZoom).image(imageUrl.get(CURRENT_IMAGE), true, true, 0, R.drawable.default_large, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ProductDetail.this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.default_large), 0);*/
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_viewpager, null);
            popupMenuImage=new PopupWindow(popupView,android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            ViewPager viewpager= (ViewPager)popupView.findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);

    how to use viewpager to swipe list of images in horizontal listview after selecting main image.

            break;
}
}

  }
```

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: whats `HorizontalListView`? is it a library?

Comment: yes it's library @mmlooloo

Comment: Why you did not use `HorizontalScrollView`?

Comment: @Shadow u have to set `adapter` using `imageUrl` arraylist for that ViewPager and use `viewpager.setCurrentItem(CURRENT_IMAGE, true);` for currently selected `HorizontalListView's` item.